# button_to custom named route returns routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I'm using Rails 3.2.3 and Haml 3.1.4.

Here's my routes.rb with the custom named route:

```
resources :netscalers do
  resources :vips
  member do
    post :refresh
  end
end
```

Here's when I run 'rake routes', I see it's defined:

```
refresh_netscaler POST   /netscalers/:id/refresh(.:format)     netscalers#refresh
```

Here is my view (app/views/netscalers/index.haml):

```
= button_to 'refresh vips for ns', :refresh_netscaler
```

Here is the error after I click the 'refresh vips for ns' button:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"refresh", :controller=>"netscalers"}
```

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like

```
= button_to 'refresh vips for ns', refresh_netscaler_path(??)
```

The ?? should be replaced by something the produces a netscaler.id,  you didn't post enough code to figure out what ?? should be.

Comment: ahh, okay. it works now. so even though it appears to point directly at the controller and action, it won't work unless you specify the id. thanks!